# Probability book recommendation: a first step into measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

So here am I studying probability theory. I am already presented to the basics, which means that I am acquainted to most of the theory proposed by Sheldon Ross' book "A First Course in Probability". Although I am very pleased at reading it, I would like to receive some suggestion of bibliography involving measure theory (for statisticians). Can anyone provide me a title? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related thread (though not exactly what you're looking for): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315075/book-on-measure-theoretic-statistics Folland is another book to be aware of; it's a popular textbook on measure theory that includes a chapter on probability. Durrett's probability textbook is good.

Comment: @littleO: Do you mean "Probability: Theory and Examples"? The book is a good read but I it would be a little heavy for a first approach to measure theory.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, that's the one, and I agree it would be a little heavy. I also think that Folland isn't the easiest introduction to measure theory. I'll be interested to see other suggestions.

Comment: The only 'text' I like were class notes from Paul Chernoff at Berkeley. Not much of a suggestion I am afraid.

Comment: Ross' *Second Course in Probability* is a fairly friendly introduction to measure-theoretic probability. There's also Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*, which is an excellent but difficult text.

Comment: This is not really a suggestion, but Kingman and Taylor's *Introdction to Measure and Probability* may worth a look. It's a bit dry, but on my first read I was pleasantly surprised that it cares to explain [how to construct a product topology for *infinitely* many topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167630/infinite-product-space). This should be a piece of useful and basic knowledge, but for some unknown reason, many textbooks only discuss finite products. So, while I have never seriously delved into it, I still remember this book to this date.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264